Hyperledger Fabric 2.5: How to modify a network/channel so that a non ordering organization becomes ordering organization and can have ordering nodes
I am trying to follow this document
https://medium.com/@amit.pitambare/adding-a-new-orderer-organization-to-an-existing-hyperledger-fabric-v2-3-channel-d0b52e6d1125
to modify the channel configuration to make an existing non ordering organization to become ordering (so it can start ordering nodes). (HLF 2.5.4 using Raft, 3 organizations, just one ordering organization for now. I used Hyperledger Bevel to create the HLF network configuration and have it running)
I get this error:
error applying config update to existing channel 'my-channel': initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Application sub-group config: Attempted to define two different versions of MSP: org4MSP

(org4MSP is the organization I want to become ordering organization). How can I do this? (I know your tutorial is about a new organization that was not already in the channel and I understand my organization already joined the channel but i can't find the way to do it for my existing org ...)
Thanks for any directions on how to do that.
